# Style Dataform label based on validation severity with Silverlight 4

Tags: validation, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I am trying to extend the Silverlight Validation to include severity. I am taking the approach of adding a special character at the beginning of the message to indicate if it is an error or a warning, and changing the style to either red or blue. I have successfully implemented this for the Validation Summery control, input controls and ValidationToolTips by specifying a custom Style and using value converters. But I can't seem to get it to work with labels.

My problem is that I can’t seem to bind the validation message. I have tried the following without any success:

OR

Can someone please provide some help or suggest an alternative approach. 
Links and or sample code is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by throwing exceptions of different types (the ValidationWarning exception for warnings). Each time when validation exception is thrown, the BindingValidationError event is triggered. In event handler I check for exception type and change the style depending on exception:

```
    private void OnBindingValidationError(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;

        if (textBox != null)
        {
            if (e.Error.Exception is ValidationWarning)
            {
                UpdateStyle(textBox, "TextBoxWithWarning");
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateStyle(textBox, "TextBoxWithError");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void UpdateStyle(TextBox textBox, string styleName)
    {
        var newStyle = (Style)Application.Current.Resources[styleName];
        if (textBox.Style != newStyle)
        {
            textBox.Style = newStyle;
            textBox.Focus();
        }
    }
```